# ggplot2_ combining line and barplot in one graph

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, line

Let's say I'm creating the grouped barplot by something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(time = factor(1:3), type = LETTERS[1:4], values = runif(24)*10)
ggplot(data, aes(x = type, y = values, fill = time)) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom='bar', width=0.55, size = 1, position=position_dodge(0.75))
```

Inside each type I want to connect all bar tops (meaning to connect 3 bars for A, 3 bars for B, and so on) with the line.
I'd like to get something like that as a result:
[image]

Is there a way to do that ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code to another logic that I prefer, that is to prepare the data before using `ggplot()`.

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(time = factor(1:3), type = LETTERS[1:4], values = runif(24)*10)

pdata <- data %>% group_by(type,time) %>% summarise(values = mean(values,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% ungroup()

pdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = values)) +
  geom_col(
    mapping = aes(fill = time, group = time),
    width = 0.55,
    size = 1,
    position = position_dodge(0.75)
  )+
  geom_line(
    mapping = aes(group = type),
    size = 1,
    position = position_dodge2(.75)
  )
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Vinicius! I actually meant to connect 3 bars inside one type. Meaning, mean values for red, green and blue bars with one line in A, another similar line for B, then one for C and one for D. Is it possible ? Thank you!

Comment: I guess the difficulty here is that x parameter is needed to create line across x coordinates. And here it's required to create the line "inside" one coordinate (like for all bars inside A coordinate)

Comment: Sorry I did not understand how is your desired output? Can you maybe draw something?

Comment: Thank you, Vinicius! Yep, please, see the example picture in the question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Now I got it, I updated my code